# Imported DLL function throws "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments" error

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I'm trying to use the MIT Kerberos implementation (using the krb5_32.dll from k4w-4.0.1 and the associated header file) to get a TGT and Service ticket.

I've loaded the krb5_init_context function which, according to the header file, google and SO, takes only 1 argument (The krb5_context struct) and populates it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "krb5.h"

typedef int krb5_int32;
typedef krb5_int32 krb5_error_code;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    

    HMODULE kerberos = LoadLibrary(L"krb5_32.dll");
    HANDLE krb5_init_context = NULL;

    if(kerberos == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load library!\n");
        printf("%lu", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Library krb5_32.dll loaded successfully!\n");
    }

    if((krb5_init_context = GetProcAddress(kerberos, "krb5_init_context")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("GetProcAddress for krb5_init_context failed!\n");   
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Function krb5_init_context loaded successfully!\n");
    }

    krb5_context context = NULL;
    krb5_ccache cache = NULL;
    krb5_principal client_princ = NULL;
    char* name = NULL;
    krb5_keytab keytab = 0;
    krb5_creds creds;
    krb5_get_init_creds_opt *options = NULL;
    krb5_error_code error_code = 0; //error_status_ok;

    error_code = (*krb5_init_context)(&context);

    printf("Error Code: " + error_code);

    while(true);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `krg5_init_context` is a HANDLE, it is not a function pointer.  If you want it to be function pointer, declare it as one.

Comment: So looking at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx and some other pages I thought it had to be a handle? Can I just assign a pointer to the output of `GetProcAddress` it instead?

Comment: See my answer.  The `HANDLE` is generic.  You need to cast the return value to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function using a pointer, you have to declare a function pointer.  In general, a function pointer (static member, global or static function) declaration looks like this:

> typedef  *return_type*  (*alias_name)(argtype_1, argtype_2,...argtype_n);

where `return_type` is the return type, the `alias_name` is the resulting name you will use to declare your function pointer variable, and the `arg1type_1, argtype_2,` etc. are the argument types that function accepts.

According to your post, `krb5_init_context` should be declared as this (using `typedef` to simplify things):

```
typedef krb5_int32 (*context_fn)(krb5_context*);  // pointer to function type
contextfn krb5_init_context;  // declare it
//...
krb5_init_context = (context_fn)GetProcAddress(...);  // get the address
//..
krb5_context context; 
krb5_init_context(&context);  // now function can be called
```

After these changes, make sure that you are also declaring the function pointer with the matching calling convention as the exported function.  If the function is `__stdcall`, then you need to specify that in the `typedef`.  If you don't do this, your function will crash.

To add the calling convention (this case, it's `__stdcall`):

```
typedef krb5_int32 (__stdcall *context_fn)(krb5_context*);
```

Comment: `typedef krb5_error_code (*context_fn)(&krb5_context);` gives `krb5_context: Illegal use of this type as an expression.`

Comment: Still getting a stack of errors from the typedef. `Error: 'krb5_context' : illegal use of this type as an expression`, `Error: 'krb5_context' : illegal use of this type as an expression`, Error: 'krb5_int32 *' : no variable declared before '='` etc

Comment: What is the exact prototype of the function you're calling?  I am posting what you're describing, so I think you need to post, from the header file, the *exact* prototype.  Also, where are you placing this `typedef`.  Is it before `krb5_context` and all of those other aliases are defined?  If so, then of course you will get errors.

Comment: `krb5_context` isn't defined in my application, it's defined in the header file that's being included.

Comment: You need to get it straightened out.  You have to declare a function pointer using the return value and arguments in the declaration, else you won't get to ever call that function via pointer.  From your link --  `typedef krb5_error_code (*context_fn)(krb5_context *);`  That is exactly what the function pointer should be declared as, according to what you've linked to.

Comment: Thank you! That compiles now. I get the runtime error about the calling convention though so do I just add the __stdcall to the typedef as well? Do you have a link that explains the calling conventions? I don't really understand them. Thanks for your patience, I haven't done much in regards to function pointers and loading functions from DLLs before. :)

Comment: See the updated answer for the calling convention.  The calling convention information can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions